# Function returned an unexpected list

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, replacement

I was trying out a question in Wellin's Programming with Mathematica that says the following.

**Question**:
Given a set of points in the plane (or 3-space), find the maximum distance between any pair of these points. This is often called the *diameter* of the pointset.

What I did:

```
Clear[x,y,pointset];
pointset={{1,5},{2,6},{4,2}} (* Set of coordinates*)
distance[{x_List,y_List}]:=Sqrt[Total[(x-y)^2]]; (*Euclidean distance function*)
Max[Map[distance,Flatten[Outer[List,pointset,pointset,1],1]] 
(* Outer will give all possible pairings of the coordinates, 
   Flatten make the list into a collection of pairs of coordinates, 
   Map will apply the distance function to all the pairs,
   and Max do the obvious thing
*)
```

For the example given above, I ran it and obtain $2\sqrt{5}$ which I expect. My problem come afterwards, I want to create a function that takes in *pointset* as argument and gives out the *diameter*. As I know the procedure above works, I defined the function as follows.

```
diameter[x_List]:=Max[Map[distance,Flatten[Outer[List,x,x,1],1]]
```

and then I ran, diameter[pointset]. The output gave me this.

```
Max[distance[{{{1,5},{1,5}},{{1,5},{2,6}},{{1,5},{4,2}}}]]....
```

While I understand that the output happened because distance is tried to be applied to the wrong type of object, I am unclear on where I went wrong. Thus, my questions are:

1. How do I fix the function such that distance is applied at the correct level?
2. Why does this happen? I expected it to work as I literally just copy pasted the working code and change the parameter *pointset* to *x*.

Thank you in advance for the read and replies.

**Edit1**: Based on suggestion from @evanb, I modified the codes into the following.

```
diameter[x_List]:=Max[Map[distance,Subsets[x,{2}],1]]
diameter[pointset]
```

which still doesn't work. However, `Max[Map[distance,Subsets[pointset,{2}],1]]` gives the desired answer.

**Edit2**: @belisarius suggested another alternative approach and checked that the code works. Still trying to find a definitive explanation to why I couldn't get the answer on my version of Mathematica 10.

Comment: It seems like there's a tiny bug in the code you wrote:  in both places, don't you mean `Outer[` and not `Outer,`?  When I make that fix, `diameter[pointset]` gives `2 Sqrt[5]`.

Comment: Also, you're likely better off using `Subsets[x,{2}]` to accomplish what you're doing with `Flatten` and `Outer`.  It should reduce redundant calculations.

Comment: @evanb Thank you; Firstly, for pointing out that typo. What I intended was for it to be Outer[, as you spotted. However, diameter[pointset] still gave me that long output. Secondly, for pointing out the Subsets[] Command, I didn't know it exist.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
diameter[x_List] := Max[EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[x, {2}]]
diameter[pointset]
(* 2 Sqrt[5] *)
```

Now, let's improve the performance **"a little bit"**. I believe the maximal distance will be realized at the points' convex hull (I'll not demonstrate it,but it's quite intuitive).

Now, if you have a lot of points Mathematica provides a convenient and fast way to find the Convex Hull. Let's use it and test the performance with and without it:

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
pointset = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3000, 2}];
diameter[x_List] := Max[EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[x, {2}]]

Timing[diameter[pointset]]
Timing[ch = ConvexHull@pointset; diameter[pointset[[ch]]]]

(* {45.328125, 1.39892}
   {0.061250,  1.39892}
*)
```

Now,YMMV but that's 45 vs .06 secs. Not bad at all for a little improvement ;)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of an alternative approach. However, I am still confused on why the function I defined does not work.

Comment: @Beer Your fucction works. ClearAll["Global`*"];
pointset = {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {4, 2}}; 
distance[{x_List, y_List}] := Sqrt[Total[(x - y)^2]];
diameter[x_List] := Max[distance /@ Flatten[Outer[List, x, x, 1], 1]];
diameter[pointset]

Comment: Thanks for checking the code. I find it weird that both you and evanb actually confirmed that the code works (which I really think it should), but I couldn't get it to work on my own computer. I am guessing that it might have something to do with my version (Mathematica 10). May I know what version you are running?

Comment: @BeerR Try this instead. It does the same thing as your function `diameter[x_List] := 
 Max[EuclideanDistance @@@ Flatten[Outer[List, x, x, 1], 1]]`

Comment: I am grateful and have tried the approach that you suggested. I have also found a workaround to find it using Table[]. I am just still confused on why it doesn't work only on my system.

Comment: @BeerR, it's likely the case that you had more than one definition of something in the kernel (likely `diameter`), which is why @belisarius suggested trying ClearAll["Global`*"].

Comment: Also, +1 for the `ConvexHull` speedup.  Didn't know about that function!

Comment: @evanb Yup. Dangling definitions are always the new users' nightmare